# How to view all information relative all slave machines in jmeter in real time

Tags: jmeter

I configured my test in this way (in windows 7):

- 1 Virtual machine is master, that run all vm slaves  with the command for a distribuited testing (from command line) and show in jmeter GUI some graphs (for example jp@gc Active thread over time , hits/sec, response time, etc..).
- 3 Virtual machine are slave, to execute the testing;

When master run the "start" to 3 slave, the test works (each slave run 6 thread), and in the GUI on master, there are only 6 thread in the graph (jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time), but in reality are 18 (6 thread for slaves, with 3 slaves).

So my question is: how can I see the total data for all slaves?

jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time = to see 18 thread (thread slave1 +thread slave2+thread slave3)
jp@gc - Hits per Second = Hits slave 1 +Hits slave 2+ Hits slave 3

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [__machineName](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function so the listeners could distinguish results coming from different nodes.

Also be aware of `mode` property which is configured to send results from slave machines each 100 results or each minute (whatever comes the first) so you might want to amend it, i.e. add `mode=Standard` line to *user.properties* file on each slave node.

```
# Remote batching support
# Since JMeter 2.9, default is MODE_STRIPPED_BATCH, which returns samples in
# batch mode (every 100 samples or every minute by default)
# Note also that MODE_STRIPPED_BATCH strips response data from SampleResult, so if you need it change to
# another mode
# Hold retains samples until end of test (may need lots of memory)
# Batch returns samples in batches
# Statistical returns sample summary statistics
# hold_samples was originally defined as a separate property,
# but can now also be defined using mode=Hold
# mode can also be the class name of an implementation of org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSender
#mode=Standard
#mode=Batch
#mode=Hold
#mode=Statistical
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on working with JMeter properties.

Be aware that sending results in case of severe load may cause network IO overhead so it might be a good idea to consider [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) instead

Comment: sorry, but the "__machineName" where where does put?  (in the 'thread group' or 'http request'?)..  thanks

Comment: see this [non answer, request for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978800/5292302)  if you like to improve your answer, then flag this comment as no longer needed

Answer (score 0):

Add the Machine Info function to the thread group name area as shown below:

[image]